# Can anyone run Linux on this mini computer?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a replacement(backup pc) for my dell xps14, my dell had run for many years and maybe dying, I don't want to interrupt my work for this reason.

I have bought a NCU, and now interesting on this one. https://www.minipcdb.com/articles/Meet-Sparo-mini-PC. I like it because it's smaller.

But I'm not sure if this computer is the same as RPI or more advanced, can run Linux.

[image: Sparo]

Anyone has experience on this? or Any suggestion?

Comment: try it! The answers only a usb drive away

Comment: I do not want buy a windows only computer. :(

Comment: the processor is supported, hard to say for sure though

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: I was worried about the need for some proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is advertised as being able to run Windows 10. So it would have NT Wifi drivers. If Ubuntu or similar does not have compatible wifi drivers then you can get the Windows wireless drivers and wrap then with NDIS for Ubuntu.

Finally, if something does not work, contact the manufacturer and ask them why it does not work with linux, chances are it does work but something is not published.